# Update a row based on another row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm working on my *wordpress* database, I would like to update my table `wp_postmeta` and set all `_order_tax` field to be calculated from `_order_total` with the formula :

> _order_tax = 0.2 * _order_total

Here is a snapshot of my database (focusing two interesting rows) : 
[image]

I want to do this update for each row where `meta_key = _order_total` but I don't know how to write that the new value should be based on the `_order_total` value **from the same `post_id`**

For example, I would like to write (symbolic language not sql):

> Where `post_id` is *1834* then update `meta_value` of row containing
>   `_order_tax` in `meta_key` column with `meta_value*0.2` of row containing `_order_total` in `meta_key` and same `post_id` as the line I want to update.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET ... WHERE ...` syntax as follows:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta w1
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta w2 
    ON  w2.post_id = w1.post_id 
    AND w2.meta_key = '_order_total' 
SET w1.meta_value = w2.meta_value * 0.2
WHERE w1.meta_key = '_order_tax'
```